# how to disable access to file WEB-INF/web.xml in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

On a tomcat 7 server used by a third party program, the WEB-INF/web.xml file is accessible from user's browser. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue today. WEB-INF/web.xml was accessible with http://example.com/WEB-INF./web.xml (mind the `.` in front of /web.xml).

This only happen on Windows servers with tomcat.

To resolve that behavior, edit `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml` and remove `allowLinking=true` (or set to false) in th `<Context ... />` tag. Then restart tomcat.

See also [Tomcat Documentation - The Context Container](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)

> allowLinking
>
> If the value of this flag is true, symlinks will be allowed inside the
>   web application, pointing to resources inside or outside the web
>   application base path. If not specified, the default value of the flag
>   is false.
>
> **NOTE: This flag MUST NOT be set to true on the Windows platform (or
>   any other OS which does not have a case sensitive filesystem), as it
>   will disable case sensitivity checks, allowing JSP source code
>   disclosure, among other security problems.**